# How to retrieve data from a database as an array in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

Normally data retrieved as an object from database in Laravel when we use `get()` function. But I want to retrieved data as an array.

In CodeIgnitor we use `get_array()`. What we use in Laravel ?

I have already tried with `toArray()`. But no result.

```
$doctor_result = Doctor::select('*')->toArray();
```

How to solve that?

Comment: show your code here

Comment: `toArray()` is correct. You did something else wrong.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad...show my code

Comment: `toArray()` is correct on an instance of the resulting collection not on Query builder. The select statement has not returned anything from the db, hence chaining `toArray()` on it would throw error.

Answer (score 4):

I got result. just change the code

```
$doctor_result = Doctor::all()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this.

```
$result = DB::table('tableName')->get();
$resultArray = $result->toArray();
```

second way, but some tricky.

```
$resultArray = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```